# View Logs of Running Tasks in AWS Opensearch through application logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, opensearch

I'm currently running some long-running AWS OpenSearch tasks that I want to track in a Cloudwatch Metric dashboard. I use update_by_query and wait_for_completion == False so the job runs on OS. It gives me back a task ID and I understand I can access the status of the job like that, but I was wondering if I can enable certain logging on the AWS OS side that can push errors to cloudwatch and directly into my dashboard?

I've looked into audit logging, but it doesn't seem to log an update_by_query request.